# fullcalendar event filter select almost working

Tags: fullcalendar, filtering

Im trying to filter events in fullcalendar on select change which almost works.

This is my dropdown

```
<select id="dropdown">
   <option value="All" data-feed="all-feed.php" selected>All</option>
   <option value="This" data-feed="this-feed.php">This</option>
   <option value="That" data-feed="that-feed.php">That</option>
</select>
```

This my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var feed = $('#dropdown').find(':selected').data('feed');

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    locale: 'de',
    editable: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    events: feed,
    eventLimit: 3,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,listWeek'
    }
});

$('#dropdown').change(onSelectChangeFeed);

function onSelectChangeFeed() { 
    var feed = $(this).find(':selected').data('feed');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', feed);
};

});
```

This works untill I click the next or prev buttons. Then all events Ive filtered  are added somehow in the "background": https://streamable.com/qnqwd

Ive also tried this function but then the events are added directly.

```
function onSelectChangeFeed() { 
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', feed);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); 
    var feed = $(this).find(':selected').data('feed');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', feed);         
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
};
```

Heres a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4j5s9yp2/5/

Comment: instead of using `events: feed` at startup, try defining `eventSources: [ feed ]`. Then it's defined as an event source from the start. And in onSelectChangeFeed, use removeEventSource rather than removeEvents. If we're just using the eventSource concept, rather than mixing events/eventSources, it might be a bit more reliable. I can't test that right now, but instinct says it's better to be consistent.

Comment: thanks for your idea, but this behaves the same way as my second function. Ive updated my question with a fiddle

Comment: oh wait. `var feed = $(this).find(':selected').data('feed');`. This is the _new_ selected feed value. It's not surprising, therefore, that it doesn't remove the _old_ selected feed, because it's not the same value. You also forgot to change `events` to `eventSources` as I suggested. This should do it: https://jsfiddle.net/4j5s9yp2/6/

Comment: works as desired. thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't quite work consistently, because you use "events" and "eventSources" interchangeably, and they are not the same concept. You also try to remove an eventSource with the wrong ID - as per the example in JSFiddle, by the time you call `var feed = $(this).find(':selected').data('feed');`, `feed` is set to the *newly* selected feed value. Therefore it cannot match it to an event source in the calendar to remove, because the event source currently defined is the *old* feed value.

This version resolves both issues:

```
var selectedFeed = $('#dropdown').find(':selected').data('feed');

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    locale: 'de',
    editable: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    displayEventTime: false,
    eventSources: [ selectedFeed ], //event source, not "events" directly
    eventLimit: 3,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,listWeek'
    },
    loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                $(this).parent().find('#loading').fadeIn( "300");
            }else {
                $(this).parent().find('#loading').fadeOut( "300");
            }
        }
});

$('#dropdown').change(onSelectChangeFeed);

function onSelectChangeFeed() { 
    var feed = $(this).find(':selected').data('feed');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', selectedFeed); //remove _old_ feed value
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', feed);  
    selectedFeed = feed; //set currently selected feed to the new value
};
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/4j5s9yp2/6/ for a working example.